# springroo console coloring

Tags: spring-roo

On one computer springroo console started colored from the first time, and on the other it started uncolored, but after some time it become colored, on the other it isn't colored at all (even after restart), what does it depend on?

colored version
[image http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/8464/roocolored.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/8464/roocolored.png)

uncolored version
[image http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/5424/roouncolored.png](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/5424/roouncolored.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are both the same version of Roo? I've seen a difference in coloring after upgrading my Roo version from M1 to M3 to Release.

Comment: equal versions `1.1.2.RELEASE [rev fbc33bb]`

Comment: Which operating systems are you running and which shell programs are you using, eg konsole, gnome-terminal, command prompt, bash, xterm, etc?
Those also influence the colour.

Comment: I have updated question and included images, they both run on windows xp

Comment: Haven't used a windows machine in over 5 years, but my gut feeling says the problem is with the command prompt itself applying its own coloring or system theme.
Back in the days, one used to be able to right click on the top left icon, click properties and change the color themes in there.